# Multilanguage site - GA account structure

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

i have a question as it comes to the GA account structure when you want to track multilanguge sites.

What the Google Analytics account should look like if you have your site under domain.com, and you have sites for multiple countries that are in the catalogues of the main domain like - domain.com/us , domain.com/au, domain.com/ru and so on. Of course i want to track the overall performance of sites and also every site separetely. In this case there should be one property with a non filtered viev with all the contry catalogues (just no filters), and mutiple vievs for every country? Only one tracker needed to track it properly?

Hope i have described it clearly, please help
Regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to coding, and more related to configuration. Post this to Webmasters instead.

Comment: For inspiration: http://www.flesheatingarthropods.org/translated-pages-to-original-in-ga/